# Is there an efficient way to compute column values in Pandas using values from previous rows based on conditional values from other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, vectorization

Consider looping through my DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Price': [1000, 1000, 1000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 1400, 1400],
    'Count': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
})

for idx in df.index:
    if df['Price'].iloc[idx] > 1500:
        if idx > 0:
            df['Count'].iloc[idx] = df['Count'].iloc[idx - 1] + 1
```

Resulting in:

|  | Price | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1000 | 0 |
| 1 | 1000 | 0 |
| 2 | 1000 | 0 |
| 3 | 2000 | 1 |
| 4 | 2000 | 2 |
| 5 | 2000 | 3 |
| 6 | 2000 | 4 |
| 7 | 1400 | 0 |
| 8 | 1400 | 0 |

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create pseudo-groups using [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), then use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to generate the within-group counts:

```
groups = df.Price.le(1500).cumsum()
df['Count'] = df.Price.gt(1500).groupby(groups).cumcount()

#    Price  Count
# 0   1000      0
# 1   1000      0
# 2   1000      0
# 3   2000      1
# 4   2000      2
# 5   2000      3
# 6   2000      4
# 7   1400      0
# 8   1400      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `mask` to hide values below 1500 and use `cumsum` to create the counter:

```
df['Count'] = df.mask(df['Price'] <= 1500)['Count'].add(1).cumsum().fillna(0).astype(int)
print(df)

# Output:
   Price  Count
0   1000      0
1   1000      0
2   1000      0
3   2000      1
4   2000      2
5   2000      3
6   2000      4
7   1400      0
8   1400      0
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works on my example. However, in case you add two more lines to my DataFrame with Price 3000 and 3000, your solution will continue counting 5, 6. I need to start over from 1, 2.